# Google Maps Authorization failure

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I know there are some posts about this issue,such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696620/google-maps-android-api-v2-authorization-failure) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184718/google-maps-v2-authorization-failure).

But my case is a bit special. Because the same source code works for another package name. So I think the only possible reason could be the google console setup. Here is the screenshot of my setup:

[image]

The first one is my testing version package name which works perfectly. The second one is my real package name which got the authorization failure. I'm using the debug.keystore to generate the sha1. And I did try to create a separated Android Key for my real package name. But I got the same error.

Does anybody can give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: in the second package, are you still using debug keystore or you have a release keystore?

Comment: I'm using the debug keystone for the second package. By the way, the problem is gone after I uninstall the application in device and rerun it. (Clean or rebuild doesn't work for me. Have to uninstall the app in device. Doesn't know why.)