# Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure, after adding the correct Android map key

Tags: android, google-maps, sha1

Google maps are not displayed. I've followed all the instructions which are as below:

1. As per the [google doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert) I got the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint.
2. I've added the fingerprint against the package name in developer API console.
3. Everything was working fine earlier, but recently maps are not working in debug mode and I'm getting authentication failure error.

[image: The log cat prints this log with different SHA-1 fingerprint]

If I add the fingerprint which is printed in android studio's logcat to developer API console, then it works fine.

My question is, why the fingerprint which I got from windows command prompt fails? 
And how to obtain the correct fingerprint which is printed in logcat of android studio? 
I'm facing this issue with three of my applications since last three weeks.

Comment: Have you check this stack overflow tickets? possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696620/google-maps-android-api-v2-authorization-failure / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184718/google-maps-v2-authorization-failure / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656480/google-maps-v2-authorization-failure-different-sha1

Comment: d.datul I have gone through it. That question is for wrong debug key. I've followed right steps to generate fingerprint for debug build as I mentioned in question. My question is different. I want to know how I can get the correct debug key, which currently I've picked from logcat